# Why would I use an else clause in a straight if/else statement?

Tags: php, syntax

I'm coding a page that requires a unique hash in the URL to load. My code, for reference sake, looks something like this:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_GET['hash'])) {
    mysql_close();
    header("Location: error.php");
    exit();
}
?>
```

My question is: if that `if` statement will redirect when it fails, should I (and more importantly, why should I) continue my code like so:

```
else {
    // More Code
}
```

As opposed to just:

```
// More Code
```

Is it just a case of good coding practice, or are there reasons behind it? Are there situations where continuing without an `else` gives different results to coding within one (other than the obvious `else if {}` clauses between them both?

I've written my code in `PHP`, but as far as I can comprehend, this would apply to a lot more languages too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you should do it. If you continue this in the code that comes afterwards, everything will already be indented 1 level more than it has to be.

The readability of the code will be compromised if you keep doing this, adding else statements and indenting the code further and further, leading to [arrow code](http://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/).

I like to create things like you did, too, because it keeps the code flat, and easier to read. There is even a pattern that describes what you are doing: `Guard Clauses / Statements`.

They **may** lead to complex situations, when you have many strange returns, ifs, loops, and whatnot. But in *most* cases, they make everything easier, cleaner and better to read.

Comment: Code readability was my thinking. That link to arrow code is nice reading. "Once your work is done, get the heck out of there!" : Unless you have variables you need to clean up/return, there should be no reason not to begin at the left margin again.

Answer (score 0):

Having an else statement is only a good coding practice. It won't change anything in what your code is doing, since you end your "if" with an "exit".

Comment: Do you have any reference that supports your statement that it's a good practice to have an else case that does nothing? I think you shouldn't make your code more complicated/harder to read than it has to be

Comment: Good coding practice don't have any official references, most of the time they're groups or companies recommendations... In this case, it's the recommendation in my company.

Comment: Actually good practices have recommendations from developers all over the world which can be found pretty easy. But I could not find anything regarding an else case with an empty body. But if that works for you it's definitely fine! No hate :)

Comment: The else doesn't have an empty body, read the question again... The question is "do I use an else which is not useful since I exit at the end of the if?"...

Comment: Sorry. Just got what you were refering to. My bad. I'll just keep the above comments for historical reasons. Though I'd still omit the else case here for the same reason as Florian would :)

Comment: Yes I understand, and for a personal project I wouldn't use the else :)

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid as possible to user exit(); , break(); and other function like goto that make your program jumping instruction.

Why ? Programmers are used to read codes with if, else if, else ... it's more intuitive and structurated. If the way to read the code is not common, the reader have to think where to continue reading after an exit(); , break() or goto ..

Comment: Wouldn't you just **stop** reading after an exit() statement, as effectively, none of the rest of the code applies?

Comment: And also `break` is no control structure from hell and has it's right to exist. I find myself using it pretty often in loops where I need to check a condition for an item only one time in the whole iteration

Comment: I agree with that `goto` can be really difficult to read. But if any programmer can't wrap his head around `break`, `return` or `continue`, they are just in the wrong place.